# Rust Object-Oriented Design Pattern

Tags: oop, rust

I'm triying to learn Rust by reading [The Rust Programming Language Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). I'm currently in chapter 17, and at the end of [Trade-offs of the State Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#trade-offs-of-the-state-pattern) you're asked to do the following:

- Require two calls to approve before the state can be changed to Published.

And the code you're given is:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Some(Box::new(Draft {})),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        self.content.push_str(text);
    }

    pub fn content(&self) -> &str {
        self.state.as_ref().unwrap().content(self)
    }

    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.request_review())
        }
    }

    pub fn approve(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.approve())
        }
    }
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }
}

struct PendingReview {}

impl State for PendingReview {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(Published {})
    }
}

struct Published {}

impl State for Published {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }

    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        &post.content
    }
}
```

So what I understand is that, **without breaking the trait signature**, you have to implement some kind of logic to `PendingReview` in order to need two approvals to change to `Published` state.

I thought of doing something like

```
struct PendingReview {
    reviews: i32,
}

impl PendingReview {
    fn add_review(&mut self) {
        self.reviews += 1;
    }

    pub fn ready_to_approve(&self) -> bool {
        if self.reviews == 2 {
            return true;
        }
        add_review();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then calling `ready_to_approve` in the `approve` function of the `PendingReview` state, but this does not work because I need a mutable reference that I don't have and I can't have it without breaking the trait signature. Also probably there are more problems in this approach that I can't see, I'm quite new to Rust actually.

I really don't know how to approach this problem, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And then calling `ready_to_approve` in the `approve` function of the `PendingReview` state, but this does not work because I need a mutable reference that I don't have and I can't have it without breaking the trait signature.

This is not accurate. The `approve` function of the `State` trait has *more* than just a mutable reference – it owns the entire `self`! You can do whatever your heart desires to it, because ownership in Rust is always exclusive.

To mutate `self` inside of `approve` you need to mark it as `mut`. But note that, unlike changing `&self` to `&mut self`, **this does not affect the signature**. This is the same as having a local variable `let x` and then deciding you need to mutate it and changing it to `let mut x`; it just tells the compiler you expect to mutate, but it's still the same variable with the same type – same is true for function parameters.

With that in mind, the `approve` for `PendingReview` can be this:

```rust
fn approve(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
    if self.ready_to_approve() {
        Box::new(Published {})
    }
    else {
        self
    }
}
```

There are a few other issues with your code that need to be fixed:

1. `ready_to_approve` needs a `&mut self`;
2. the call to `add_review()` is not valid, you have to say `self.add_review()`.

You can see for yourself that it compiles and doesn't break the trait's signature ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23deed053e5814b95ccea208193a0d4e)).

Comment: Quite an interesting answer. Not only did they solve the problem, but it also taught me some Rust concepts I hadn't figured out on my own. However, there is a better approach to do what I need to do in terms of sw design / 'Rust correctness' (if that makes any sense)?

Comment: I think this is more or less what the Book expected for this exercise. As for SW design this is subjective, but the pattern of encapsulating everything in the state and then requiring ownership of it to change it is pretty clean.